# Can I trust the .Length property on IFormFile in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload

We have an API endpoint that allows users to upload images; one of its parameters is an IFormFileCollection.

We'd like to validate the file size to make sure that the endpoint isn't being abused so I'm checking the `Length` property of each `IFormFile`, but I don't know whether I can trust this property or not, i.e. does this come from the request? Is it considered 'input', much like `Content-Length` is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have an `IFormFileCollection` parameter, and you send data using a "form-data" content-type in the request, that parameter [will be bound](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2e4274cb67c049055e321c18cc9e64562da52dcf/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/MvcCoreMvcOptionsSetup.cs#L129) by a [whole](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4ef204e13b88c0734e0e94a1cc4c0ef05f40849e/src/Http/Http/src/Features/FormFeature.cs) [lot](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/fc9e48877c75562af1d3879a57694f55d5685397/src/Http/WebUtilities/src/FormReader.cs) of [plumbing](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/86728ecc17c339f699d21c8abd5ee93037b51a1e/src/Http/WebUtilities/src/MultipartReaderStream.cs) that's hard to dig through online, but if you just debug the action method that accepts the `IFormFileCollection` (or any collection of `IFormFile`, really)and inspect the collection, you'll see that the uploaded files will already have been saved on your server's disk.

That's because the entire multi-part form request's body has to be read to determine how many files there are, if any, and form parameters, and validate the request body's format while it's reading it.

So yes, by the time your code ends up there, you can trust `IFormFile.Length`, because it's pointing to a local file that exists and contains that many bytes.

You're too late there to reject the request though, as it's been already entirely read. You better fix rate and size limits lower in the stack, like on the web server or firewall.

Comment: I see. I thought `IFormFileCollection` was a lazy collection, but it seems I was mistaken. I need to look more closely at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#upload-large-files-with-streaming), then.

Answer (score 3):

`Content-Length` is  compressed number of bytes of data in the body ,  it is not reliable since it may include extra data ,for example , you are sending multipart request  .  Just use the `IFormFile.length` for features like calculation or validation .